# how to edit text in multiple columns in vim

Tags: vim, vi, multiple-columns

How can I edit my code in Vim by displaying it in any number of columns?

My laptop and desktop monitors are widescreen (I suspect that is true of most monitors made in the last 5 or 10 years!).  When I open any editor in full screen, more than half the screen is completely empty.  I'd like to be able to effectively use the rest of the screen by splitting it into two or three columns so I can see all much more of my code in a single screen.

Frankly, I'm surprised that other than Microsoft Word, I have never seen this functionality in any editor.

I found the following page (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns) which seems to do what I want, but I don't really understand what they are suggesting. I did set columns and scroll bind, but that didn't seem to do anything.

I don't normally use Vim, but if I can get access to this functionality, I'll switch happily. I am currently on Ubuntu 10.10 (gnome). The default version of Vim seems to be 7.2 (/usr/bin/vim.gnome).

Comment: Does this belong on Superuser?

Comment: Clearly falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers."

Comment: @brillout what do you mean by "looking for an up-to-date" answer? Do you have a particular question/problem? It is probably better to open a new one if the answers below don't help you.

Comment: The solution of the accepted answer is not reliable and the scrolling of the two panes get out of sync all the time. I'm surprised there isn't a better solution to this. Would love something reliable! It would effectively double my read estate...

Comment: @brillout IMO, perhaps it is better to open a new question, there you can reference this one, and describe why the answer here doesn't help you and make an example to show the problem. This question has already an accepted answer, perhaps it was not working for you, but the OP has accepted it, that means, it is done.

Comment: You're right, thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just press `CTRL-W v` and the file you are working on will be split into two separate independent columns. Repeat `CTRL-W v` as many times as you want.

Set scrollbind: `set scrollbind` to columns that you want to scroll in sync.

For example:

```
vim afile         # Open a file
^w v              # split it
gg                # go to top
:set scrollbind   # bind this one
^w l              # go to the new split
L                 # go to bottom of this split
zt                # make it the top line
:set scrollbind   # bind with this one
```

Now, while you move on one column, the other one scrolls so as if the first column overflows the text to the second column.

Comment: wow, this is tantalizingly close! I can see the same file in two columns and they scroll together. However, I don't want mirror images in the two columns, I want text from the first column flow into the next columns. Say my file just has numbers from 1 to 10k. I expect to see, say, 1-60 in the first column, 61-120 in the second columns, etc.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I had a typo. It does what you want. I think I'll update with a more complete function later.

Comment: This seems to do what you describe: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns

Comment: This solution is not reliable and the scrolling of the two panes get out of sync all the time. I'm surprised there isn't a better solution to this. Would love something reliable! It would effectively double my read estate..

Comment: You can make a more sophisticated function to handle your edge cases but the main point will still be using `scrollbind`.

Comment: Note: `set scrollbind` only works when you are in the new pane. I’m guessing there's a reason for that but I don't see what exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is split windows...

Type `:Vexplore` to split a window vertically.

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>arrowkey</kbd> to navigate to another window. `:Sexplore` will enable you to split the window horizontally.

To evenly space after resizing, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: :*explore and :split seems to allow me to open two different files at the same time. I actually want to split the same file across multiple columns. Just like long lines automatically flow to the next lines, I expect long text to overflow over to the next column.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Yes, it will open a browser so to speak. But you can open the same file twice or as many times as you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns.

It's a little clunky... Sometimes the scroll synchronization gets offset or disconnected, forcing you to re-columnate the view (in cmd mode, `CTRL+W`,`q` to close a a col. window, & `\vs` to add one.).

But it works great 90% of the time.  I use it a lot.