# How to make vim code folding sync across splits?

Tags: vim

I'm trying out [code folding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141097/how-to-enable-and-use-code-folding-in-vim) in vim but noticed it doesn't seem to mirror across pane splits when using `scrollbind` to achieve a "2-up" view of a long text/code file with relatively narrow lines (set up as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131298/2668831) guidance).

Is it possible to ensure a fold created in one pane is also created on the other?

I'm just getting familiar with the commands, but it'd probably be <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (close a fold at the cursor, i.e. 'fold up') and <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (open a fold at the cursor, i.e. 'unfold')

It strikes me that one use of code folding would be to let one of the split views be an "outline view" (fully folded up, and just used to give an indication of how far through the file the other pane is), but it'd be nice if I could get them fully synced for `scrollbind`.

Answer (score 0):

```
nnoremap <Space> za<C-W><C-W>za<C-W><C-W>
```

in `.vimrc` allows you to toggle a folding simultaneously in two splits by pressing the space bar.